# Memory access comparison

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Which one of the 2 is faster (C++)?

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum_a = sum_a + a[i];
    sum_b = sum_b + b[i];
}
```

Or

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum_a = sum_a + a[i];
}
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum_b = sum_b + b[i];
}
```

I am a beginner so I don't know whether this makes sense, but in the first version, array 'a' is accessed, then 'b', which might lead to many memory switches, since arrays 'a' and 'b' are at different memory locations. But in the second version, whole of array 'a' is accessed first, and then whole of array 'b', which means continuous memory locations are accessed instead of alternating between the two arrays.

Does this make any difference between the execution time of the two versions (even a very negligible one)?

Comment: You could test it and find out.  Simple math will tell you you have twice the number of iterations in the second example.

Comment: But he does have a point about cache hits/misses.

Comment: I don't think there is correct answer for this due to different architectures

Comment: Interesting: both GCC and clang keep two loops, Intel compiler combines them in one.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot how big were the arrays? Were the arrays stored adjacent in relation to each other?

Comment: @user2079303 I was interested in default behavior in case of inability to predict all use cases, so both arrays were extern const pointers, n was function argument and sum_a/sum_b were returned as pair. Of course in case of inlining and with more intimate info about arrays compiler will do better.

Comment: I think it would also change with size of object, i.e. when you want to access one variable from objects in array, as this would mess with prefetch and cache.

Comment: This can depend on far too many factors. One obvious factor is whether `n` is a compile-time constant, because the optimizer may take advatnage of that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is correct answer to this question. In general, second version has more twice as much iterations (CPU execution overhead), but worse access to memory (Memory access overhead). Now imagine you run this code on PC that has slow clock, but insanely good cache. Memory overhead gets reduced, but since clock is slow running same loop twice makes execution much longer. Other way around: fast clock, but bad memory - running two loops is not a problem, so it's better to optimize for memory access.

Here is cool example on how you can profile your app: [Link](https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/random-acts-optimization)

Answer (score 3):

> Which one of the 2 is faster (C++)?

Either. It depends on

- The implementation of `operator+` and `operator[]` (in case they are overloaded)
- Location of the arrays in memory (adjacent or not)
- Size of the arrays
- Size of the cpu caches
- Associativity of caches
- Cache speed in relation to memory speed
- Possibly other factors

As Revolver_Ocelot mentionend in their observation in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327947/memory-access-comparison#comment64070822_38327947), some compilers may even transform the written loop into the other form.

> Does this make any difference between the execution time of the two versions (even a very negligible one)?

It can make a difference. The difference may be significant or negligible.

Your analysis is sound. Memory access is typically much slower than cache, and jumping between two memory locations may cause cache thrashing <sup>†</sup> in some situations. I would recommend using the separated approach by default, and only combine the loops if you have measured it to be faster on your target CPU.

<sup>†</sup> As MSalters [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327947/memory-access-comparison/38328465?noredirect=1#comment64075180_38328465) thrashing shouldn't be a problem modern desktop processors (modern as in ~x86).

Comment: Cache thrashing with two arrays is prevented by a 2-way associative cache (or better). It's only a problem with direct mapped cache. Accessing two physically distinct memory locations at the same time may even double the memory bandwidth, depending on your memory architecture.

Comment: @MSalters OK, it shouldn't be that bad then. But you could still only fit two arrays of size N / 2, compared to a single array of size N into the cache, couldn't you? Maybe my reasoning is off. I admit, I do most of my optimization at higher level than this.

Comment: @user2079303 the memory pre-fetcher will easily tell that you are accessing the memory in this linear fashion.  The pre-fetcher is not as fast as the cache, but it's much faster than waiting the full amount of time for a memory access.

Comment: @user2079303: in a one-pass algorithm, you don't need to fit the whole array in cache. The chief function of the cache is then to read 64/128 bytes at a time from main memory, and allow you to process them in far smaller chunks. A completed cache line can be evicted from the cache again. Sure, you have _two_ active cache lines if you work on two arrays at the same time, but that generally is a _good_ thing.

Comment: @user2079303: You seem to be a bit pessimistic about cache associativity. Even an embedded ARM Cortex A8 processor (not at all new) has 4-way associativity, which means it can process 4 arrays. That's enough for even 3-operand functions with a 4th destination (i.e. `A[i] = B[i] * C[i] + D[i]`)

Comment: @MSalters and here I thought that I was too optimistic, since 8086 didn't have cache at all (I think) :) I'm trying to convey that in practice all desktops have multi-way associative cache which I'm fairly confident to say. I don't know much about vast variety of embedded processors, so I don't have the same confidence. If the arrays are processed in half sized block, doesn't that mean that there are twice the number of memory fetches? Wouldn't the fetches likely be the bottleneck of the loop? If the fetches can be made in parallel, I suppose that wouldn't matter then.

Comment: @user2079303: The 8086 did in fact have cache. 6 bytes, IIRC. On modern systems, the fetches would be for whole cache lines at a time, but with one loop the cache line fetches would alternate.